# A question about notation in a 1976 paper by Bousfield and Gugenheim

Tags: notation, simplicial-stuff

I am reading the paper *On PL De Rham theory and rational homotopy type* by Bousfield and Gugenheim. It was published in 1976, so some notation is kind of different to what I'm used. In particular, I'm unsure about the use of $\{,\}$ at page 8.

Let $\mathcal{S}$ be the category of simplicial sets, $\mathfrak{M}$ the category of $k$-modules. Given a contravariant functor
$$K:\mathcal{S}\longrightarrow\mathfrak{M},$$
they define a new contravariant functor $\widehat{K}$ with the same domain and range by
$$\widehat{K}(X) = \prod_{n\ge0}\prod_{x\in X_n}\{K(\Delta^n),x\}.$$
What are these brackets? Are they simply considering the $k$-module obtained by taking the product of one copy of $K(\Delta^n)$ for each element in $X_n$, that is
$$\widehat{K}(X) = \prod_{n\ge0}K(\Delta^n)^{X_n},$$
or is it something completely different?

**Edit:** To add to the same question, they go on defining the action of $\widehat{K}$ on maps as follows. Let $f\in\mathcal{S}(X,Y)$, then for $m_y\in K(\Delta^n)$, $y\in Y_n$ we define
$$\widehat{K}(f)\{m_y,y\} = \{m_{f(x)},x\}.$$
I can't make sense of this expression. I am trying to understand what the "obvious" action of $\widehat{K}$ on functions should be. My idea so far is that as $y\in Y_n$ can be seen as a morhism of simplicial sets $y:\Delta^n\to Y$, let $x\in X_n$ be such that $f(x) = y$. Then we can write down a commutative square
$$\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
X @>f>> Y\\
@AxAA @AAyA\\
\Delta^n @>>\operatorname{id}> \Delta^n
\end{CD}$$
and apply $K$ to it, remembering that it is contravariant:
$$\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
K(X) @<K(f)<< Y\\
@VK(x)VV @VVK(y)V\\
K(\Delta^n) @<<\operatorname{id}< K(\Delta^n)
\end{CD}$$
This makes me think that we should rather have something like
$$\widehat{K}(f)\{m_y,y\} = \prod_{x\in f^{-1}(y)}\{m_y,x\},$$
where we see $m_y\in K(\Delta^n)$, which was associated to $y$, as an element of the copy of $K(\Delta^n)$ associated to $x$. Does this make sense?

Comment: Calling a 1976 paper old-ish makes *me* feel old ...

Comment: Yes, I think it is just the product of a copy of $K(\Delta^n)$ for each $x \in X_n$.

Comment: @lhf Thanks. I've added a small piece to the question. Do you have any idea, by any chance?

Comment: @Hagen von Eitzen: I clicked on this question thinking that it might be something from the mid 1800s to early 1900s (a period from which I've "read" -- i.e. looked over -- literally thousands of papers) and maybe I could help, rather than the usual Euler, Newton, etc. eras that I've hardly penetrated into. Then I saw 1976 . . .

Comment: @DaveL.Renfro Well, I wrote old-ish and not old for that reason. But ok for the change of title ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that's right, $\hat{K}(X) = \prod_{n \ge 0} K(\Delta^n)^{X_n}$. The extra $x$ in the notation is just to know which factors comes from where. I think today people would rather write something like $\{ m_y \}_{y \in Y_n, \, n \ge 0}$, so that's what I'll do.

Now suppose that you have a simplicial map $f : X \to Y$. You want to define a map $\hat{K}(Y) \to \hat{K}(X)$. An element of $\hat{K}(Y)$ is a collection $\{ m_y \}_{y \in Y_n, \, n \ge 0}$, and $m_y \in K(\Delta^n)$ for $y \in Y_n$. To this you want to associate a collection $\{ m'_x \}_{x \in X_n, \, n \ge 0} \in \hat{K}(X)$ (where $m'_x \in K(\Delta_n)$). What they do is they simply set $m'_x = m_{f(x)}$.

(Reading this section, it seems they're implicitly taking the methods of acyclic models for granted, it might help you to read a bit about it before reading their work. I've written [a blog post about it](https://blog.erad.fr/2016/01/15/acyclic-models/) if you want, and there are references at the end.)

Comment: Ah, I see! I assumed that $\{x_y,y\}$ was the element given by $m_y$ at "position" $y$ and $0$ everywhere else instead a whole the collection. i have already seen proofs using acyclic models in algebraic topology (e.g. working on CW complexes), but I'll certainly take a look at your blog. Thanks!